# Photon speed is it the same as light speed?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, speed-of-light

The speed of light is about 186000miles per sec. however, the light is also a wave. If the photon follows the wave path, then to progress at 186000miles / sec. in a linear direction must be accompanied by the photon traveling along this wave at a faster rate. this should depend on the wavelength or colour. Is this so? and if not then how are these facts reconciled?

Comment: Photons aren't particles traveling along a wave of light

Answer (score 1):

> however, the light is also a wave

No, it is not.

All elementary "particles" are quanta. They are not really particles and they are not really waves. If you ask them what their wavelength is it will happily tell you an answer, but that does not mean it is "waving". So...

> in a linear direction must be accompanied by the photon traveling along this wave at a faster rate

No, [that's just not what's happening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_quantum_mechanics). There is a thing moving at c, and depending on what you measure it with it might look like a wave or a particle, or both or neither. The confusion is because we're using classical terms for "wave" and "particle" to refer to something that just isn't. Don't worry, this has been confusing everyone for 100 years now.